# Async function does not return a response

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am new to `Javascript`. I am trying to read a few files and construct a `JSON` object response. I am able to run the entire code, however, one last piece is remaining, I am not getting a response from the `async` function.

```js
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs/promises');

const getProductDetailByProductID = async (id) => {
    const productsFile = path.join(__dirname, 'turing_tasks', 'products.json')
    const customersFile = path.join(__dirname, 'turing_tasks', 'customers.json')
    const reviewsFile = path.join(__dirname, 'turing_tasks', 'reviews.json')
    const imagesFile = path.join(__dirname, 'turing_tasks', 'images.json')

    const { products } = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile(productsFile, 'utf-8'))
    const product = products.filter(product => product.id === id)[0]

    const {reviews} = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile(reviewsFile, 'utf-8'))
    const {customers} = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile(customersFile, 'utf-8'))
    const {images} = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile(imagesFile, 'utf-8'))

    const reviewsData = []
    reviews.forEach((review) => {
        customer = customers.filter(customer => customer.id === review.customer_id)
        if(customer) customer = customer[0]
        const reviewImages = images.filter(image => review.images.includes(image.id))

        reviewsData.push({
            "id": review.id, 
            "rating": review.rating,
            "customer": customer,
            "images": reviewImages
        })
    })

    return {
                    "id": product.id,
                    "name": product.name,
                    "reviews": reviewsData
                }
}
```

```js
(async () => {
  const result = await getProductDetailByProductID(1);
  return result
})();  // This does not fetch anything
```

I am running this file using below command

```
nodemon task.js
```

Also, please recommend a better way of writing this code if it is poorly written. Please share a link for the same.

Comment: An async function returns a Promise.  You need to use `Promise.resolve` or `getProductDetailByProductID(1).then(...)` to get the result.

Comment: Did you use the await keyword? Async function returns a promise, you get the result of the promise with the await keyword

Comment: Mixing `await` with `.then()` is a great way to produce very confusing code. I suggest you stick to one form and one form only

Comment: @Phil what is the right way of simplifying the code. Please suggest some link.

Comment: Just don't use `.then()`. Write the code as if it was all synchronous but use `await` for any async operations. For example... `const { products } = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile(...)); const product = products.find((p) => p.id === id);`

Comment: @Phil Awesome thanks. Can you please recommend me how to become good at writing promises? Any good practice material online that takes you from beginner to advanced level?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your getProductDetailByProductID is async, you should call your getProductDetailByProductID like this:

```
(async () => {
  const result = await getProductDetailByProductID(1);
  console.log(result);
})();
```

more:

```
getProductDetailByProductID // this function is async and return a Promise value
```

if you want get the value:

```
function ss ()  {
  const result = await getProductDetailByProductID(1);
  console.log(result); // your getProductDetailByProductID's return value
  return result;
}
ss()
```

if you still return value from async function, also need use async await to get value

```
sync function s2() {
  const result = await ss();
  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code, however this time IIFE from your answer does not return a response. It only logs the response. I have tried return result. Can you please help?

Comment: @wayne, don't worry, I will explain to you.

Comment: The result would also be asynchronous so you also need to await it: `let x = await (async () => { .....; return result})()`

Comment: @wayne, I understand what you mean. But since it's an async function, if you want to get the return value inside the async function, you have to use `Promise().then()` or `await` to get the value. `async function ss ()  {
  const result = await getProductDetailByProductID(1);
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

(async function s2() {
  const result = await ss();
  console.log(result);
})()`

Comment: @MWY This is working, however it is confusing as it is a chain of function calls.
Can you please update your answer as well

Comment: @wayne, sure, explain more